# Does lightning have pressure?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, forces, energy, pressure, lightning

Hi do lightning have pressure if yes what is it ? Nikola tesla has invented the artificial lightning so can we make it ?

Comment: The shock wave from lightning can be heard from quite far away.

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Can you be a bit more precise what you mean by "lightning" having pressure? Pressure is a property of substances, but "lightning" is more a flow of current than a substance. Are you perhaps asking whether lightning leads to pressure changes in the air it is conducted through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lightning bolts have a very high temperature of up to [30000K](https://hypertextbook.com/facts/1999/DavidFriedman.shtml), one hundred times room temperature (300K). My guesstimate: at 1 bar equilibrium pressure that would increase the pressure to 1000 bar instantly, using the ideal gas law. This causes a outward shock wave that will reach your ears as thunder.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing is left intact after the lightning has touched it, so "yes" and it depends on particular circumstances.

Comment: A strange response given that lightning regularly touches things and they're still intact afterwards.

Comment: @StephenG: So lightnings are not dangerous, are they?

Comment: *Nothing is left intact after the lightning has touched it* This is simply not accurate.  Ever heard of a lightning rod ?

Comment: Yes, I have heard of them. They are used to avoid damage from lightnings.